# Permission problem in TYPO3 v8 for non admin users

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

Users in the editor group ("Redakteure") are not allowed to edit two content elements, the two bottom ones, which were created by me, the admin. The users in the group are allowed to edit their own content element, the top one. The creator of the page is a member of the editor group and the permissions say they should be allowed to edit it, but the edit button is not visible for them. "Restrict editing by non-Admins" is not active on these two elements.

How can I give a user or group edit permissions to all content elements on one page?

Admin view:
[image: Admin view]

User view:
[image: User view]

Permissions:
[image: Permissions]

User is in the group:

[image: User groups]

Comment: The top one seems to be of a different cType (different icon)... Have you checked "Explicitly allow/deny field values" -> "Page Content: Type" in the backendgroup? Maybe the editors are not allowed to use the two other content elements.

Comment: That did indeed work! I just thought that the bottom element had to be included before, but it was a HTML-Element and not a simple text field. Thank you very much @JulianHofmann !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some permissions in the backend usergroup «Redakteure». Use the list module on page [0] and edit the backend usergroup «Redakteure».

In tab «Access Lists» at bottom allow the content elements «Table» and «Regular Text Element»:

- Explicitly allow/deny field values: Page Content: Type: Text
- allow/deny field values: Page Content: Type: Table

[image: TYPO3 backend usergroup permission]